# Serverless Framework deprecation issue I can't fix

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

When I try to install serverless framework I get the following deprecations.  I've run an npm install on each individual package. Npm says the package installs worked, but it doesn't change the sls output.   I reinstalled Windows thinking I may have changed a config file at some point, still the exact some output even after reinstall.  I'm running Windows 10.  I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.

C:\Users\User>npm install -g serverless

npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes

npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these deprecations are related to the libraries version that are used directly by `serverless`. You can expect them to sooner or later be addressed on that library level but until that, you can use it without worries (unless you see the explicit security warnings, but that's not the case at the moment).

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.   I'll go see if I can get a project going.